# Asp.Net MVC catch 404 for unknown extensions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm able to catch almost every 404 but this:
**http://example.com/mariajosefa.pedro de heredia**

The file "mariajosefa.pedro de heredia" doesn't exists.

This seems to be catched by IIS and my users are presented with the standard IIS 404 error page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quick answer :( for reference, this is what works for me:

In web.config:

```html
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/Home/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>

ALSO REMOVE THE COLON FROM THE INVALID CHARACTERS LIST, THIS WAS ALSO BOTHERING ME

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\,?"/>
```